# How to verify the convergence rate in Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: estimation, simulation, monte-carlo

Given a iid random samples $X\sim N(\theta,1)$, we have a unknown parameter $\theta$ and its estimator $T_n=T_n(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.  If we have strictly proved that the convergence rate is
$$
|T_n-\theta|=O_p(N^{-1/3})
$$
It seems that $T_n$ is a consistent estimator.

I would like to verify this convergence rate in the Monte Carlo simulation. I'm a little unclear on which quantity should I plot the Monte Carlo estimate? Is it Mean square error MSE? Say I have 1000 samples and each sample is repeated 500 times. It can be drawn that the MSE gradually converges to the x-axis as the number of samples increases.

I try to simulate the for a fix $\epsilon>0$,
$$
P(|T_n-\theta|>\epsilon)
$$

I fix $\epsilon =0.01$ and sample size $n=1000$. That is the mean of $|T_n^{j}-\theta|>\epsilon$ for replications $j=1,\dots, 30$. But I got the following result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work 100%, but to show that your estimator has the convergence rate of $O_p(N^{-\frac{1}{3}})$ and you want assess it, from the definition for any given $\epsilon > 0$:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Pr(|T_n - \theta| > \epsilon) = 0 $$
So to evaluate this visualize I would suggest fixing some small $\epsilon$ and for each $n$ simulate $|T_n - \theta|$ several times, and calculate the empirical $Pr(|T_n - \theta| > \epsilon) $ and plot it. And with this you can see how the convergence will behave against $N^{-\frac{1}{3}}$. BTW it isn't prove anything, you need to make the theoretical calculations to demonstrate any statement.

Comment: Thank you! But what is the empirical of $P(|T_n-\theta|>\epsilon)$? For example, if we fix $\epsilon=0.01$ and $\theta=0$, that is $P(|T_n|>\epsilon)$. I am not sure what is the Monte Carlo estimate of this distribution．

Comment: What I have done is about the simulation of the expectation. For example, the empirical of expectation is the average of $\frac{1}{N}\sum T_n^j$ where I draw $T_n^j$ from each samples, $N$ is the number of replications.

Comment: To calculate the empirical $P(|T_n - \theta|) > \epsilon$ one way is fix $n$ and $\epsilon$ and simulate let's say for example 100 times $T_n$, and $i$ be the index of the simulation and then calculate $mean((|T_n^i - \theta|) > \epsilon)$ ,

Comment: Can you please see my edit? I simulate the mean of $|T_n^i-\theta|>\epsilon$. But the result is wired?

Comment: Yes, is the mean of this expression. I don't know what result being wired mean.